# Яка етимологія слова "джгут"

Tags: етимологія

**Джгут** - еластична гумова трубка, бинт або інші подібні предмети, якими перев'язують кінцівки для припинення кровотечі.

Цікавить етимологія цього слова, бо [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1985/EtSlUkrM_1985.pdf#page=47) (ст. 47-48) не дає однозначної точної відповіді (наскільки я зрозумів походження слова не зовсім ясне). А саме хотів би дізнатися чи не є це слово запозичене (а якщо запозичене, то з якої мови). Спроби пошуку в Інтернеті не дали ніяких результатів, але можливо хтось знає ще й інші джерела звідки можна взяти інформацію про етимологію цього слова.